# Battery consumption of android by observer and service

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in which I want to monitor files. So what I am doing I have created a service in which I am registering an file observer which will monitor the file changes.

As soon as some events take place it will take the metadata of all the files in sd card and updates the application database by replacing the old data with the new one.

So I just wanna know should I register the observer in a service or in a activity to save battery of the user and what will be the better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to monitor when user is using the app, place observer code in activity. If monitoring is to be done all the time, use service. Clearly, app requirements decide the choice here.

An active service may consume more battery because it may detect more file changes and may be triggered frequently.

If the observer can notify about exact files which change, you can update only the changes.

Another optimization is to run database updates in a batch  after a considerable number  of  updates are collected, instead of using the database for each update.

Answer (score 1):

For battery life it shouldn't matter (you still use the CPU independent of which class you extend)

It sounds like a service rather than an activity, so I would have chosen a service.

For conserving battery you can do a few things depending on what your goal is.

1. the FileObserver should give you a direct path to the file that is being accessed/changed, so maybe you doesn't need to re-scan all the files on the sd-card?
2. let the service just store the paths to the files changed, and do nothing more in the service. Then when they start our apps Interface, start an async-task and process them in the background. that should be pretty fast depending on the number of files that has been changed between the times you application started up.